# Inspection not working with an ode

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Let us consider the following first order ode:

$$y'+y \cos x=\cos x$$

Inspection method would suggest to test with $y_p=A \cos x+ B\sin x$ as a candidate for particular solution, but it doesn't work (neither does $y_p=p(x)\cos x+q(x)\sin x$ no matter the degree of the polynomials $p$ and $q$).

One gets that the actual solution, with "variation of constants" method is:

$$y=1+C e^{-\sin x}$$

and this tells us that we should have tested $y_p=1$ as a candidate for particular solution, which is not in the form of the candidates that inspection method suggests to test in this case.

Is there a precise reason why the inspection method does not work here?

Comment: There is no such method. It would be peculiar if the solutions of *all* equations were of that form, right?

Comment: @Mark_Hoffman: Can't you use Separation of Variables?

Comment: @Moo Yes, separation of variables and variation of constants work fine.

Comment: You can also make it a linear equation or an exact equation and use an integrating factor. This is the reason why we want an arsenal of tools to solve problems, so we can use the right tool for the job. Doesn't look like Undetermined Coefficients (which is what I think you are referring to in the problem statement) is a good approach here.

Comment: Your "inspection method" only work for *constant* (non-variable) coefficients, which this equation doesn't have.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This "inspection method" only works for linear ODE with constant coefficients, as then the basis solution are of the type "polynomial times exponential" (trigonometric functions are also combinations of exponentials). If then also the right side is also a sum pf terms of that type, then the particular solution can be constructed by this method.